# Exception in Application start method. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException javafx8

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, stack-trace

I'm Getting this error and I can't seem to figure out exactly what wrong. It was working just fine three days ago and now I am unable to run it. I see that is having troubles with the image url, but I've double checked the url and tried an alternate with no luck. I don't understand why it was working a few days ago when I haven't changed anything.

Here is the code:

```
public class MCobbM10A2 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView("images/Black_Cat.png");
        imageView.setFitHeight(100);
        imageView.setFitWidth(100);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);
        PathTransition pt1 = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(2000)
            ,new Line(100, 100, 750, 500), imageView);
        pt1.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        PathTransition pt2 = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(500)
            ,new Line(750, 500, 600, 550), imageView);
        pt2.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        PathTransition pt3 = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(1600)
            ,new Line(600, 550, 50, 150), imageView);
        pt3.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        PathTransition pt4 = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(360)
            ,new Line(50, 150, 100, 100), imageView);
        pt3.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        SequentialTransition s = new SequentialTransition(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4);
        s.play();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Cat Move");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
     /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
Executing C:\Users\cmatt\Desktop\MCobbM10A2\dist\run1883417844\MCobbM10A2.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at javafx.scene.image.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:166)
    at mcobbm10a2.MCobbM10A2.start(MCobbM10A2.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    ... 12 more
Exception running application mcobbm10a2.MCobbM10A2
Java Result: 1
```

EDIT:
Here's the new Error:

```
C:\Users\cmatt\OneDrive - Lincoln Land Community College\Spring 2020\CSC 176\Netbeans Projects\MCobbM10A2\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3867: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\cmatt\OneDrive - Lincoln Land Community College\Spring 2020\CSC 176\Netbeans Projects\MCobbM10A2\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3904: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\cmatt\OneDrive - Lincoln Land Community College\Spring 2020\CSC 176\Netbeans Projects\MCobbM10A2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1134: Directory C:\Users\cmatt\OneDrive - Lincoln Land Community College\Spring 2020\CSC 176\Netbeans Projects\MCobbM10A2\dist creation was not successful for an unknown reason
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Does MCobbM10A2.jar contain an `images/Black_Cat.png` entry?

Comment: @VGR I'm not sure. How do I check?

Comment: On the command line, `jar tf C:\Users\cmatt\Desktop\MCobbM10A2\dist\run1883417844\MCobbM10A2.jar | findstr "Black_Cat"`.  If you don’t want to use the command line, make a copy of that .jar, change the copy’s extension to `.zip`, and open it as a zip file.